# Управление кнопками с геймпада в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui, unity3d-ui

такой вопрос - как можно реализовать взаимодействие с UI элементами при помощи геймпада? В Unity установлен New Input Manager. Игра под XBox. Есть идея написать скрипт, который будет симулировать мышь, но опять таки не знаю, как реализовать?

Comment: Есть же Input.GetAxis

Comment: У меня игра под Xbox One и вроде бы там мыши просто нет.

Comment: Input.GetAxis это должно работать для геймпада, wasd и для стрелок. И возможно даже для VR джостика

Comment: @Andrew , мне нужно, чтобы, например, стиками джойстика можно было выбирать нужные кнопки. Разве у Unity не встроена такая де система, как и для клавиатуры?